# java.lang.ClassCastException: myClass cannot be cast to class java.util.List

Tags: java, list, exception, classcastexception

I have a class setup called `MyClass` that holds two lists:

```
public class MyClass {
    List<String> list1;
    List<Descriptor> list2;

    public List<String> getList1() { return list1; }

    public List<Descriptor> getList2() { return list2; }

    public void setList1(List<String> list1) { this.list1 = list1; }

    public void setList2(List<Descriptor> list2) { this.list2 = list2; }
}
```

In a different class, I want to create an `object` based off of `MyClass` and supply that object to a method

```
MyClass class = new MyClass();
class.setList1(someList);
class.setList2(otherList);
return Response.status(HttpStatus.OK_200).entity(class).build();
```

the method `.entity` takes an object but I get thrown the `java.lang.ClassCastException` error and can't figure out why.

Everything supplied is a List so I don't understand why this error is getting thrown

Comment: `MyClass` is not a `List`.

Comment: What package is `Response` from?

Comment: Note: The variable `class` does not reference a class -- it references an instance of a class.   And it's a keyword.

Comment: Can you please share the Response class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying: MyClass (the entity) consists of lists, therefore it is a list.

That's as crazy as saying: My house is made of bricks, therefore my house is a brick.

The central job here is taking the thing you pass to the `entity()` method and turning that into a sack of bytes, because the HTTP protocol sends bytes. How does that work? That's where you need to learn how your tools and libraries work: I'm assuming that you're using Jersey/JAX-RS here. That is set up as follows:

- You can send **any object at all** back.
- However, that object is spooled through a bunch of registered 'translators' that each have the ability to translate a subset of object types into a stream of bytes. Out of the box, the system knows how to 'translate' Strings (that's trivial - convert the strings to bytes using `.getBytes(someCharsetEncoding)`, voila - bytes) and a few other things. But you can add on more translators if you want. That is why the `entity()` method takes any Object.
- Some registered translator assumes they are lists when they are not, causing your error. (Because you have an instance of `MyClass`, which isn't a list. Sure, all its fields are lists, but, a house is not a brick).

But the solution (probably) isn't in fixing that 'translator'. First think it through: What are you actually trying to *do* here? HTTP just sends bytes, so what bytes do you want to send? That `MyClass` object needs to be turned into bytes one way or another. How should that go? What service is calling this? What does it do?

Here's one example answer:

Some website has javascript that makes an AJAX call to this endpoint and turns whatever it receives into a javascript object by parsing it with a JSON library, or just `eval()`ing it.

If that is your answer, that you want your `MyClass` entity to be turned into JSON. [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson) can do that for you.